# deeplearning4j embedding more than one field

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, embedding, deeplearning4j

How can I embed more than one field in deeplearning4j?

For example, if I want to embed `user_id` and `ad_id` as two fields:

```
 val conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
  .seed(12345)
  .optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.STOCHASTIC_GRADIENT_DESCENT).iterations(1)
  .activation(Activation.LEAKYRELU)
  .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
  .learningRate(0.01)
  .updater(Updater.NESTEROVS).momentum(0.9)
  .regularization(true).l2(1e-4)
  .list
  .layer(0, new EmbeddingLayer.Builder().nIn(FEATURE_DIMS).nOut(512).activation(Activation.IDENTITY).build())
  .layer(1, new DenseLayer.Builder().nIn(512).nOut(10).build)
  .layer(2, new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.NEGATIVELOGLIKELIHOOD)
    .activation(Activation.SOFTMAX)
    .nIn(10).nOut(1).build)
  .pretrain(false)
  .backprop(true)
  .build
```

This code only embeds one field in deeplearning4j. How can I embed more than one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you will be using a ComputationGraph based network. A ComputationGraph can have multiple inputs, and that would allow you to use multiple Embedding Layers at the beginning.

For more on that take a look at the documentation:
https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/models/computationgraph#example-2-multiple-inputs-and-merge-vertex

Comment: thank you for your answer,but it need multidataset for train(multi inputs is onehot feature),how to structure the multidataset?